# UIWebview App Crash After HTML Video Plays

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, uiwebview, brightcove

I have a crash that occurs after a HTML-5 video finishes playing from a UIWebview. The UIWebview loads a page which contains a brightcove embedded video player. The video launches fine and the video plays. However if you watch the video in Landscape and then press done, when are taken back to the UIWebview and interact with that (eg start scrolling) the app crashes with:

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 15
1    UIKit   -[UIWindow warpPoint:] + 710
2    UIKit   _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 3382
3    GraphicsServices    _PurpleEventCallback + 590
4    GraphicsServices    PurpleEventCallback + 34
5 ...    CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 34
11   UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1120
```

NSZombies reports:

```
*** -[MPTransportButton _isChargeEnabled]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x258f75d0
```

The project uses ARC and I am **not** natively playing the video it is all handled by the UIWebview in an embedded player. So this apparent memory management issue is internal to the UIWebview managed code.

I suspect it has something to do with the Orientation changes as it seems to be related to watching the video in landscape. Unfortunately this is a requirement.

The embedded brightcove code can be found in a related link on their support forums [Brightcove Crash](http://forum.brightcove.com/t5/HTML5-Mobile-Video/Native-app-UIWebView-with-Brightcove-player-crashes-once/td-p/22654)

I have seen other questions but no answers [UIWebView Crash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075134/uiwebview-load-crash-nscfdictionary-ischargeenabled) and [UIWindow warpPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479139/ios-app-crash-issue-uiwindow-warppoint)

Comment: You're not using the media framework anywhere else in your app?

Comment: @dml no we are not using the media framework elsewhere, which is why this is so frustrating! The video playback is all managed by the default UIWebView behaviour.